# Does SignalR work with series 40?

Tags: signalr, series-40

I'm trying to use SignalR, but I want to know whether it's supported on series-40, specifically whether it's supported on Nokia Asha phones. Anyone knows? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, I successfully get it working using Nokia Web Tools. Please refer to [This blog post](http://agilefromthegroundup.blogspot.com/2012/09/getting-signalr-and-phonegap-working.html) for things that you need to do to make it work.